# large text from database in textarea

Tags: java, text, netbeans, textarea, long-integer

I have the synopsis from a list of films saved in a database, I want to show that text in a 
*TextArea* when the user clicks in the table a specific film.
When it happens, the text appears all in one line and destroys the structure of my `jFrame`.
How could I give some format to that text? I'm working at Netbeans IDE.

```
 ResultSet rs2=DB.Sinopsis(code);
    try{
        while(rs2.next()){
            TextSynopsis.setText(rs2.getObject("sinopsis").toString()); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setLineWrap(boolean)` property of JTextArea ie if TextSynopsis is an object of JTextArea

Answer (score 1):

You could use the setWrapStyleWord(true) and setLineWrap(true) on your textArea object.